# Is it possible to influence a single Angular app from multiple JS scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Quick Summary:** 
I need to allow two script files to handle different operations for the same angular app. One needs to initialize the app, the other needs to assign a templateCache object to a piece of JSON in localStorage.

**Context:**
I have several python files which compile/generate html and I have constructed an angular app with this emitted html for my site (which uses CGIs).

The basic construct of the site comes pieces of HTML, which fit together like so:

```
|------------Header---------------|
|-Navigation-|------Content-------|
|-Navigation-|------Content-------|
|-Navigation-|------Content-------|
|------------Footer---------------|
```

My Header creates the `<head>` tag, instantiates my `ng-app` and uses `$templateCache` to set up a template that I call from my Navigation code. I had to go with templateCache instead of `ngView` and `ngRoute` due to some limitations with how the CGIs emit the html, and the order in which this happens.

My "Navigation" python/html sets up my app with JS like so:

```
<script>    
var responsiveCatalog = angular.module('responsiveCatalog', ['ngStorage']);
....controllers...
....config, etc....
</script>
```

This Navigation also includes my default templateCache object:

```
<div ng-include=" 'responsiveItems.html' "></div>
```

This is all working to show my first templateCache object in the Content section. However, I need to grab many pieces of information from the python generator for the "Content" section (a totally separate file from the "Navigation"), store this data as JSON in localstorage (hence the inclusion of the `ngStorage` module), and call that as my second templateCache option.

I am not actually sure that I can use two separate instances of Javascript to reference and influence the same Angular app. I know this seems like bad practice, but I am trying to prevent the need to tear down a huge piece of legacy architecture to influence the angular app from two Javascript files in harmony.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the "Content" section is another javascript file which is supposed to add template strings to $templateCache, and this "Content" section is loaded a little while after the angular app bootstraps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do
`angular.module('myAppName').controllers....` in different files, just make sure the `myAppName` the same. Bug I don't feel like it work with `config`, no time to test. If you need any communication between them, check `$emit` and `$broadcast`.